# Docker-Compose: Initialize vs Run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm migrating an existing rails application to docker and docker-compose. There are a few scripts that need to run only at the creation of the containers, for instance a script that copies the prod db into a volume and and indexes it in Elasticsearch.

From then on, when I start the containers locally for development, I only want to run the rails development server and not all the db init scripts. I could make two docker-compose files (say `init` and `run`) that are the same except for the `command:` option on the webapp container.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

The base Docker system doesn't have an "on run" concept for custom scripts.

What you can do is one of these approaches:

- Add to your script a check of if it already has done that. Then it doesn't matter if you re-run it again and again.
- Integrate the db into the docker and ship it as already made with the data loaded.
- Make a 2 part docker system: The 1st would be the docker you know now with a possible "ONBUILD" command so the 2nd one would run the script. Then the 2nd docker is a one inhering the original one and would run the script with or without the "ONBUILD" above. In docker-compose you would have a local build which would trigger the import while creating the local docker image.

Just an idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extends` in your compose *.yml files.

[Extend documentation and examples.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extends)

Comment: "When you extend a service, links and volumes_from configuration options are not inherited - you will have to define those manually each time you extend it." Still better than creating an entire new docker-compose file, but not as dry as it could be. I really only want one or two lines to be different between the two docker-compose files, so the extension docker-compose should only be one or two lines long too.